# What is the point of having a special integer $N$ in the definition of a limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definition

I don't quite understand what we are trying to show when we find an $N$ such that $\forall n\geq N\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $|a_n-L|< \varepsilon$. For example I have been experimenting a bit with the function $$f(n)=\frac{n}{n+1}$$

When put into the definition of the limit $\Rightarrow |\frac{n}{n+1}-1|= |-\frac{1}{n+1}|=\frac{1}{n+1}<\varepsilon$, So now we take $N$ such that $\forall n\geq N$ we have $\frac{1}{n+1}\leq\frac{1}{N+1}<\varepsilon$ which gives us $N>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}-1$, now I'm not entirely sure as to why we don't just use this expression with $n$ instead of $N$, I suppose what I'm asking is why do we bother to introduce this special $N$ when we could just show that for every $\varepsilon$ we can find $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_n-L|<\varepsilon$

For example we could just take $\varepsilon>\frac{1}{n+1}>\frac{1}{n+2}$ so then for every $\varepsilon >0$ if we take $n=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}-2$ we clearly have an $n$ that will satisfy any epsilon.

Comment: Let $f(n) = (-1)^n$ and $L = 1$. Given any $\epsilon > 0$, I can find an $n$ (infinitely many $n$, in fact) such that $|f(n) - L| < \epsilon$ (in fact $|f(n) - L| = 0$) but this doesn't imply that $f(n) \to 1$.

Comment: But $N$ depends on $\epsilon$. The definition of a limit is saying that no matter how small we make $\epsilon$, we can always find some real number $N$, such that every term $a_n$ (where $n\ge N$) of the sequence is closer than $\epsilon$ to L. You can't use the same name for $n$ and $N$ here because they mean different things. $N$ is fixed for fixed $\epsilon$ but $n$ can vary anywhere above $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to express the idea of "this is true for all n that are significantly large enough".  This won't be true for *all* n, just those that are larger than a certain threshold.  That threshold will change depending on the value of $\epsilon$ (in general the threshold will get larger as $\epsilon$ gets smaller).  The N is simply the threshold.